How to optimise subqueries in BigQuery views
I have a table that contains tons of nested columns as well as repeated columns. I use a BQ view on top of it that does some transformations. For example, something like this:
view1:
SELECT
nested.field1,
nested.field2,
nested.field3,
nested.field4,
nested.field5,
( SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(SAFE_CAST(data.json AS STRING), "$.value")
  FROM UNNEST(nested.field6) as data
) as field7
FROM mytable

Now, when I query the view like this:
SELECT
field1
FROM view1

It is taking a lot of time and I can see in the BQ execution details that the subquery is computed even so I did not select the column.
Now, in the view, if I delete the nested fields2 to 5, there is no change in computation time nor in the amount of data processed. It means BQ is smart enough to see that when I select field 1, it does not need to return something else from the view. So my question is, why BQ still execute the subquery that generate field7 even so the field is not selected?

Is there an EXPLAIN type command for google?  In Mysql using that on a statement can return information as to why its taking so long to execute.
